Where in Aristotle's Metaphysics is Aquinas citing his claim about "two sorts of operations"?
In the beginning of book II of Aquinas's Summa Contra Gentiles, Aquinas writes

Now the operation of a thing is twofold, as the Philosopher teaches in
9 Metaphysics ...

A footnote is provided which reads "D. 8, viii. 9." What does this mean? Book 8.8.9? Book 9.8.8?
And, in any event, what line in the Metaphysics is Aquinas referring to? If this is the passage that Aquinas is referring to, I don't see how it's relevant.

It is book 9, part 8, as in your link, "where the result is something other than the exercise of the faculty, the actuality resides in the thing produced... But where there is no other result besides the actualization, the actualization resides in the subject." Compare to "one that remains in the agent... another that passes over into an external thing" in Aquinas.

It seems that your proposal is the right one; 1050a24:

"And while in some cases the exercise is the ultimate thing (e.g. in sight the ultimate thing is seeing, and no other product besides this results from sight), but from some things a product follows (e.g. from the art of building there results a house as well as the act of building), yet none the less the act is in the former case the end and in the latter more of an end than the mere potentiality is. For the act of building is the thing that is being built, and comes to be—and is—at the same time as the house."

It is Met, Bk IX (Theta), Ch.8. [I've used Oxford edition].
It "sounds" similar to Aquinas's second paragraph: "Now the operation of a thing is twofold, as the Philosopher teaches in 9 Metaphysics: one that abides in the very worker and is a perfection of the worker himself, such as to sense, to understand, and to will; and another that passes into an outward thing, and is a perfection of the thing made that results from it, such as to heat, to cut, and to build."
If we agree that this is the corresponding text, we have to compare Aristotle "exercise" with Aquinas' "operation" and the twofold distinction is that between "the ultimate thing" (of the operation) that is a "perfection of the worker himself" vs the product of the operation, that is "the perfection of the thing made".
Here perfection is actuality.

Thank you Mauro! Can you just explain then what is meant by "D. 8, viii. 9."?

@Doubt - no idea, sorry. If the ref is correct, it must be IX.8 (and thus viii.9 can be a typo). D.8 maybe the code referring to some edition: the eight volume of ... You have to check on the site you are using about it: due to the fact that the ref to A 's works into Aquinas ones will be many, maybe there is some preliminary note explaining the code used for references.
